# Wide and deep tensorflow tutorial keeps getting 0 accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I took the wide&deep tensorflow tutorial, and I used it on my own dataset. I basically changed just the columns names and tensors. I want to predict a float value "valeur". But I keep getting 0 accuracy. Someone care to explain why ?

```
COLUMNS = ["idPCE", "typeObj", "heure", "typeG", "pas",
           "qualite", "valeur"]
LABEL_COLUMN = "label"
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ["idPCE", "typeG", "pas", "qualite"]
CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS = ["heure"]


def maybe_download(train_data, test_data):
  """Maybe downloads training data and returns train and test file names."""
  if train_data:
    train_file_name = train_data
  else:
    train_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://mlr.cs.umass.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data", train_file.name)  # pylint: disable=line-too-long
    train_file_name = train_file.name
    train_file.close()
    print("Training data is downloaded to %s" % train_file_name)

  if test_data:
    test_file_name = test_data
  else:
    test_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://mlr.cs.umass.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.test", test_file.name)  # pylint: disable=line-too-long
    test_file_name = test_file.name
    test_file.close()
    print("Test data is downloaded to %s" % test_file_name)

  return train_file_name, test_file_name


def build_estimator(model_dir, model_type):
  """Build an estimator."""
  # Sparse base columns.
  idPCE = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket("idPCE", hash_bucket_size=1000)
  typeG = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_keys(column_name="typeG",
                                                     keys=["DENMOY","ENETER","ETHMOY","METMOY","PCSMOY","PREMOY","TEMMOY","VOLBAL","VOLBCP","VOLBCR","VOLCAL","VOLCCU","VOLTER"])
  pas = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_keys(column_name="pas",
                                                     keys=["H","J"])
  qualite = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_keys(column_name="qualite",
                                                     keys=["A","AA","AD","AF","CS","M"])

  # Continuous base columns.
  heure = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("heure")



  # Transformations.
  heure_buckets = tf.contrib.layers.bucketized_column(heure,
                                                    boundaries=[
                                                        6, 12, 18
                                                    ])

  # Wide columns and deep columns.
  wide_columns = [idPCE, typeG, pas,
                  qualite,heure_buckets,
                  tf.contrib.layers.crossed_column([typeG, qualite],
                                                   hash_bucket_size=int(1e4)),
                  tf.contrib.layers.crossed_column(
                      [heure_buckets, idPCE, pas],
                      hash_bucket_size=int(1e6)),
                  tf.contrib.layers.crossed_column([heure_buckets, qualite],
                                                   hash_bucket_size=int(1e4))]

  deep_columns = [
      tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(qualite, dimension=3),
      tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(pas, dimension=1),
      tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(typeG, dimension=4),
      tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(idPCE,
                                         dimension=3),
      heure
  ]

  if model_type == "wide":
    m = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(model_dir=model_dir,
                                          feature_columns=wide_columns)
  elif model_type == "deep":
    m = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(model_dir=model_dir,
                                       feature_columns=deep_columns,
                                       hidden_units=[100, 50])
  else:
    m = tf.contrib.learn.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(
        model_dir=model_dir,
        linear_feature_columns=wide_columns,
        dnn_feature_columns=deep_columns,
        dnn_hidden_units=[100, 50],
        fix_global_step_increment_bug=True)
  return m


def input_fn(df):
  """Input builder function."""
  # Creates a dictionary mapping from each continuous feature column name (k) to
  # the values of that column stored in a constant Tensor.
  continuous_cols = {k: tf.constant(df[k].values) for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS}
  # Creates a dictionary mapping from each categorical feature column name (k)
  # to the values of that column stored in a tf.SparseTensor.
  categorical_cols = {
      k: tf.SparseTensor(
          indices=[[i, 0] for i in range(df[k].size)],
          values=df[k].values,
          dense_shape=[df[k].size, 1])
      for k in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS}
  # Merges the two dictionaries into one.
  feature_cols = dict(continuous_cols)
  feature_cols.update(categorical_cols)
  # Converts the label column into a constant Tensor.
  label = tf.constant(df[LABEL_COLUMN].values)
  # Returns the feature columns and the label.
  return feature_cols, label


def train_and_eval(model_dir, model_type, train_steps, train_data, test_data):
  """Train and evaluate the model."""
  train_file_name, test_file_name = maybe_download(train_data, test_data)
  df_train = pd.read_csv(
      tf.gfile.Open(train_file_name),
      sep=';',
      names=COLUMNS,
      skipinitialspace=True,
      engine="python")
  df_test = pd.read_csv(
      tf.gfile.Open(test_file_name),
      sep=';',
      names=COLUMNS,
      skipinitialspace=True,
      engine="python")

  # remove NaN elements
  df_train = df_train.dropna(how='any', axis=0)
  df_test = df_test.dropna(how='any', axis=0)

  df_train[LABEL_COLUMN] = pd.to_numeric(df_train["valeur"])
  df_test[LABEL_COLUMN] = pd.to_numeric(df_test["valeur"])


  model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp() if not model_dir else model_dir
  print("model directory = %s" % model_dir)

  m = build_estimator(model_dir, model_type)
  m.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train), steps=train_steps)
  results = m.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_test), steps=1)
  for key in sorted(results):
    print("%s: %s" % (key, results[key]))


FLAGS = None


def main(_):
  train_and_eval(FLAGS.model_dir, FLAGS.model_type, FLAGS.train_steps,
                 FLAGS.train_data, FLAGS.test_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.register("type", "bool", lambda v: v.lower() == "true")
  parser.add_argument(
      "--model_dir",
      type=str,
      default="",
      help="Base directory for output models."
  )
  parser.add_argument(
      "--model_type",
      type=str,
      default="wide_n_deep",
      help="Valid model types: {'wide', 'deep', 'wide_n_deep'}."
  )
  parser.add_argument(
      "--train_steps",
      type=int,
      default=200,
      help="Number of training steps."
  )
  parser.add_argument(
      "--train_data",
      type=str,
      default="",
      help="Path to the training data."
  )
  parser.add_argument(
      "--test_data",
      type=str,
      default="",
      help="Path to the test data."
  )
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

Here's a line on my csv dataset (47000 for train and 10000 for test) :

> NSVCUCOG;PCE;05;DENMOY;H;AF;0.619

The output :

```
accuracy: 0.0
accuracy/baseline_label_mean: 46.8802
accuracy/threshold_0.500000_mean: 0.0
auc: 0.5
global_step: 200
labels/actual_label_mean: 46.8802
labels/prediction_mean: 1.0
loss: -5.34063e+07
precision/positive_threshold_0.500000_mean: 0.998047
recall/positive_threshold_0.500000_mean: 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data label must be a range,eg. [0,1,2...].

tf.contrib.learn.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(
            n_classes=5,

Because every float number is treated as a label ,and the default classes number is 2.

That's all I can explain with my own experience!

Comment: thanks for the answer, but 5 classes make no sense because my output could be any float. I come to realize that a DNNClassifier could not resolve this(Definitly not a classification). Although using a DNNRegressor doesn't get me much further with 6.98953e+06 loss ... I have even more data now (200 000 rows) ..